# Javascript Recursion normalize JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, reduce

I have a json response and I want to simplify this json data with recursion and reduce. I write a function put i stuck at this point. I want to remove all data element and create a new object without data name.

My json data is like this

```
[
    {
        "city": {
            "data": {
                "id": 649442,
                "country_id": 54,
                "state_id": 682,
                "city_name": "Prague",
                "state_name": "Praha"
            }
        },
        "country": {
            "data": {
                "id": 54,
                "data": {
                    "country_name": "Czech Republic",
                    "short_country": "CZ",
                    "olympic_code": "CZE"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And my function is here:

```
function normalizeData(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((finalObject, objectKey) => {
    if (object[objectKey] && object[objectKey].data) {
      finalObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey].data;
      if (Array.isArray(finalObject[objectKey].data)) {
        finalObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey].data.map(item => {
          return normalizeData(item);
        });
      } else {
        finalObject[objectKey] = normalizeData(object[objectKey].data);
      }
    } else {
      finalObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey];
    }
    return finalObject;
  }, {});
};
```

At the and I am still getting data object. So where am I making mistake. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO Tan! To get clarity, you wish to delete certain keys and get new, cleaned object. Right? But what should happen to object with `id=54`?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid type data so id: 54 should be like this

{
  "country": {
      "id": 54
   }
}

Comment: it would help if you could put an example of the input and the expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution without `reduce()`, that checks if the object properties are not inherited (`hasOwnProperty()`), and does a recursion for each property that is an object itself. It the property key is `data`, then all the values get copied to the parent object and the `data` key gets deleted from the object afterwards. This is where it gets tricky because the `data` object can have a `data` property itself, so this has to be checked and a double recursion needs to be applied.

```js
var jsonStr = `{
    "city": {
        "data": {
            "id": 649442,
            "country_id": 54,
            "state_id": 682,
            "city_name": "Prague",
            "state_name": "Praha"
        }
    },
    "country": {
        "data": {
            "id": 54,
            "data": {
                "country_name": "Czech Republic",
                "short_country": "CZ",
                "olympic_code": "CZE"
            }
        }
    }
}`;

var jo = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

function normalize(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                if (key === 'data') {
                    // check if data object also has a data property
                    if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty('data')) {
                        // double recursion
                        normalize(obj[key]);
                        normalize(obj);
                    }
                    else {
                        // copy all values to the parent
                        // (only if they don't exist in the parent yet)
                        for (var subKey in obj[key]) {
                            if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty(subKey)
                            &&  !obj.hasOwnProperty(subKey)) {
                                obj[subKey] = obj[key][subKey];
                            }
                        }
                        // remove the data key
                        delete obj[key];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // recursion
                    normalize(obj[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

normalize(jo);

console.log(jo);
```

you can use a [deep extend](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#deep_extend) to create a copy of the object first and return that one, if you don't want the function to modify the input.

Comment: OK, it is a solution, but also a highly convoluted function: No separation of concerns, hardly reusable.

Comment: @ftor yes it is, but it's also not too hard to make it reusable, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I have an array on top of the object :) so I fixed the code like this.

```
export function normalizeData(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((finalObject, objectKey) => {
    if (object[objectKey] && object[objectKey].data) {
      finalObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey].data;
      if (Array.isArray(finalObject[objectKey].data)) {
        finalObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey].data.map(item => {
          return normalizeData(item);
        });
      } else {
        finalObject[objectKey] = normalizeData(object[objectKey].data);
      }
    } else {
      finalObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey];
    }
    return finalObject;
  }, {});
}

export function normalizeArray(array) {
  return array.map(object => {
    return normalizeData(object);
  })
}
```