# Normalise Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a json object with objects inside of it
such as `user: {"name": "tim"}` and would like a way to turn that in `"user.name": 'tim'`

I've tried: [Javascript Recursion normalize JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788868/javascript-recursion-normalize-json-data)

Which does not return the result I want, also tried some packages, no luck

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: This question needs clarity, way too many "what-ifs" come to mind when attempting to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive approach to flatten nested objects, by concatenating their keys, as shown below:

```js
const flattenObject = (obj) => {
  const flatObject = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const value = obj[key];

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      const flatNestedObject = flattenObject(value);

      Object.keys(flatNestedObject).forEach((nestedKey) => {
        flatObject[`${key}.${nestedKey}`] = flatNestedObject[nestedKey];
      });
    } else {
      flatObject[key] = value;
    }
  });

  return flatObject;
};

const obj = {
  user: { name: 'tim' },
};

console.log(flattenObject(obj));
```

This solution works for any amount of levels.

If your environment does not support [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), you can use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead:

```js
const flattenObject = (obj) => {
  const flatObject = {};

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    const value = obj[key];

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      const flatNestedObject = flattenObject(value);

      for (const nestedKey in flatNestedObject) {
        if (!flatNestedObject.hasOwnProperty(nestedKey)) continue;
        flatObject[`${key}.${nestedKey}`] = flatNestedObject[nestedKey];
      }
    } else {
      flatObject[key] = value;
    }
  }

  return flatObject;
};

const obj = {
  user: { name: 'tim' },
};

console.log(flattenObject(obj));
```

Comment: Hey @KyllianSurname, I think you are using an old version of JS that does not support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys. Hold one, will edit my answer to include a version with `for-in`.

Comment: @KyllianSurname Done, you can take a look at the current version of the answer.

Comment: But I am not 100% sure if this is your issue. The code should work fine, as you can see when you run the snippet.

Comment: Thanks @Alberto but now I get `(node:18448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at flattenObject (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\WebFaster\hw-api\routes\v1\properties.js:11:23)`

Comment: How does your object look like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2gEw8kbp it's a mongodb collection but quite big.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217364/discussion-between-kyllian-surname-and-alberto-trindade-tavares).

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done like so:

```js
const myObject = {
  user: {
    firstname: "john",
    lastname: "doe"
  }
}

function normalize(suppliedObject = {}) {
  const newObject = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(suppliedObject)) {
    for (const subKey of Object.keys(suppliedObject[key])) {
      newObject[`${key}.${subKey}`] = suppliedObject[key][subKey];
    }
  }
  return newObject;
}

console.log(normalize(myObject));
```

Be aware that this only normalizes 1 level deep. You can extend the function to normalize all the way down to the last level.

Comment: How would it look for 4 levels?

Comment: Another user beat me to it, their answer is the one for all levels :)